# - db Error Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": Failed to lookup host: registry-1.docker.io

Tags: python, mysql, docker, flask

I'm very new in docker.I want my python project runs in another system that mysql and python are not installed on them.

Here is the docker-compose.yml created by me:

```
version: "3"
services:
    db:
        container_name: mydb
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
            - "32001:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    app:
        container_name: myapp
        links:
            - "db"
        build: ./
        ports:
            - "5001:5000"
```

and the Dockerfile:

```
    FROM python:3.9
    COPY . .
    RUN pip install mysql-connector-python pandas
    CMD ["python", "project.py"]
```

when I want to build the images for the project with:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

this error will be appeared:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": Failed to lookup host: registry-1.docker.io
```

and the project.py:

```
import mysql.connector
db = mysql.connector.connect(host = 'mydb', user = 'root', password = 
'root', port = 3306)
```

Comment: This could be due to a network issue or a problem with your Docker installation.make sure you have Docker installed and running correctly on your system `sudo systemctl status docker` If Docker is not running, you can start it using: `sudo systemctl start docker` and restart it